# Duplication not getting in shape its in reverse direction

Tags: dupli-groups

Im making duplication. Problem is the shape is getting duplication but the shape is reverse as its getting to the other end. Another problem is that its not going flat way. At the end its getting tilted one side. I have applied scale+rotation+location to both curve and the mesh. Whats going wrong.[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object on curve wont stay flat!](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat)

Comment: @atek duplication is not mirroring... the "red" side is perfectly legit imho, it just follows the curve... if you want your duplication to be mirrored along globalX, use half curve and then set up mirror on global X

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos the duplicate link give is different the mesh is changing its shape and its getting tilt upward also. can u give solution for my mesh thanks

Comment: Have you tried that solution? What happened when you did? Also make your curve 2D

Comment: @m.ardito i never said i need mirror. I said that the object is not turning to its shape its going wrong direction as marked in green and red

Comment: @atek: what you are saying you want IS mirroring. Your shape starts following the curve (as parent) from right to left, and thus it points in that direction too. Then, your curve points backwards (left to right) and your shape still follows the curve (it couldn't do differently) and thus it points "opposite" respect to your expectation, but it's perfectly normal: it just follows the curve. You could use only the bottom part of the curve ("green" part) and then mirror all (curve and your shape following it) on X global axis.

Comment: @m.ardito thanks but why the below answer section disappeared

Comment: @atek? I didn't add (or delete) any answer... maybe others? who knows. Do you need an example posted as answer?

Comment: @m.ardito yeah if possible with gif file . How it works for you all and not for me. Maybe something im missing from 1st i mean adding the curve and making it dupliframe. One thing im getting problem when i click object and curve and hit ctrl+p and object the mesh goes other way not in this question. How to solve that. Thanks

Comment: can you show a reference of what you're trying to achieve?