# How can I apply curve modifier to a mesh without it changing position?

Tags: transforms, transform-orientation

Basically I have 3 meshes connected to each other I want them to rotate in the positions they are in but I also need them to bend at a certain point. The rotation is fine the problem is with the bending. The bending effect will be done with a curve modifier. The curve will change shape at a certain point and I'll save it as a *shape-key*. The problem is when I apply a *curve modifier* to one of the meshes and choose the curve that passes through the three meshes, the mesh changes position and messes up the whole thing. how do I apply a curve modifier while maintaining the position of the mesh I apply it to?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787

Comment: I don't think that's it, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Recommend add *what exactly* does not solve your issue in order to re-open your question.

Comment: Z-up in the object data of the curve. It didn't change anything for me.

Comment: That was more of a related question, check the lined duplicate at the top