# Object tilts along animation constraint path

Tags: animation, constraints

I have attached an object along a constraint path, When the path is flat the object follows along accordingly. I then make one point elevated so the object can heave then dive along the path. All up to the blue line its perfect, then once it comes down the slope, the object is tilted all along till the end of the path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the curve and choose *Twist Method > Z-Up*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, that's crazy feature hiding there. I was clicking all the options in the follow path constraint section!...Would never had thought looking at the Z-up option.

Comment: you could have tilted the vertices but that's not the best solution