# Geo Nodes: Curve to Mesh Normal/Tangent control

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a staircase with Geometry nodes and it has gone great so far (using blender 3.0)

However, when I try to create the floor, if I make a quadrilateral to follow the curve it goes a bit crazy. I assume because of the tangents or normals of the curve.

[image]
[image]

Is there a way of controlling this? Here are my nodes.

[image]

I am aware 3.0 is under development, but just wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat