how to apply tilt to a path?
I have this path:

and i want to move the last vertex, to make a little curve, but this happens:

how can i apply a tilt, like in ctrl + A
changing the "twist method" to "z-up" didn't work (Object on curve wont stay flat)

see the file here:


hello could you please share your object (only this part)? https://blend-exchange.com/

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/

You blend file upload: you only pasted the picture of the download image, you need to copy the whole resulting string into your post.  Make sure to test, test, test, by clicking on the image after your edit to verify it goes to the download page.

To add to StefLAncien's answer, you can improve the result a bit if you open the Active Spline panel, activate the Bézier U option and play with the Order U value:


(Using Blender 3.6.8)
The issue could be that the distance between control points close to the tip is less than the "thickness" of the extruded curve, even after deformation by the Radius. The following picture illustrates how moving along the Z axis just two control points could improve the shape.

