How can I create a loop with a pathcurve set as a bevel for an archemedian curve object?
I want to create a loop like the picture below. I made the basic shape with an archemedian curve. I read on another post (Trying to make a plane follow a bezier curve)
that it is possible to use another curve to create that desired effect instead of using a plane and matching up origin points.
So I set the basic path curve as bevel for the main object aka the archemedian curve. However, when I do this, I get the result as seen in the second picture. How can I make sure it is a flat loop?



https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87253/can-i-extrude-a-path-in-x-y/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/object-on-curve-wont-stay-flat/

Your bevel object needs to be correctly oriented:

Also you'll need to tilt some of the spiral vertices:

You could also create your object with a mesh and the Screw modifier:


Ah, the screw modifier worked for me. But I am still curious, what do you mean with the bevel objects needs to be correctly oriented? Like what needs to be correctly oriented in regards to what?

I meant maybe the bevel object orientation was your problem in your file but it's hard to say without the file, please share the file
